# How do get background of p element to cover image (ie issue)

Tags: css, background, background-image

I changed z-index of the p element, but it won't cover the part of the image I'm attempting it to cover - I believe it's an ie issue as this works with firefox and chrome.

css of p element

```
#slidearea .scrlCntr p{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    margin-top: -20px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding:0;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: Z-index won't work with position: static; (the default). Setting position: relative; should fix it.

Comment: Thanks - just fixed issue with your help & first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, it needs `position`: "absolute, relative ..."

```
   #slidearea .scrlCntr p{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
        margin-top: -20px;
        opacity: 0.9;
        padding:0;
        z-index:999;
        position:relative;
    }
```